# filter_fields in django rest framework viewset are ignored

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get some basic equality filtering for my view and if I understand the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend), I only need the `filter_fields()` field defined.

Well, they seem to be ignored (`/api/organizations?ticker=AMZN` lists everything instead of filtering down to a single record):

```
class OrganizationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    filter_fields = ('sector', 'industry', 'marketplace')

    @staticmethod
    def pack_persons_to_url(request, data):
        data["persons"] = request.build_absolute_uri("/api/persons/%s/" % data["symbol"])

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(OrganizationViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        for element in response.data["results"]:
            self.pack_persons_to_url(request, element)
        return response

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(OrganizationViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pack_persons_to_url(request, response.data)
        return response
```

The first three fields are FKs and the `ticker` is a `CharField`. What do I need to fix to make it all work right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `DjangoFilterBackend` to the filter backends of your viewset

```
filter_backends = (backends.DjangoFilterBackend, )
```

Answer (score 13):

I was experiencing this after upgrading to `django-filters` 22.1. It seems `filter_fields` was renamed to `filterset_fields`.